# What are the specific conditions that cause Unity3D's AndroidJavaClass to throw on new?

Tags: android, exception, plugins, unity-game-engine, stack-trace

This code throws on new AndroidJavaClass:

```
    public static bool Initialize(ref string msg)
    {
        if (instance_ == null)
        {
            GameObject newGameObject = new GameObject("EstimoteDeviceController");
            newGameObject.AddComponent<EstimoteDevicePlugin>();
            instance_ = newGameObject.GetComponent<EstimoteDevicePlugin>();

        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            try
            {
                using (AndroidJavaClass androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("EstimoteBeaconActivity"))
                {
                    instance_.androidActivity_ = androidClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mContext");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                msg = e.StackTrace;
                Debug.LogWarning("[EstimoteDevicePlugin] - Initialize(): exception thrown: " + msg);
                return false;
            }
        #endif

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Generates this stack trace when it throws :

```
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr clazz.IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject] (System.String.methodName.System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject] (System.String.methodName.System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._AndroidJavaClass (System.String className) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.AndroidJavaClass (System.String className) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at EstimoteDevice.EstimoteDevicePlugin.Initialize (System.String& msg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've searched for this and so far have not found a conclusive answer to *why* is happens, only that it does, and the plug-in vendor (e.g. Facebook) have addressed it in a later version of their plug-in.

I've repeated this with Android SDK tools 23, Android platform + builds tools 19 + 20, SDK v4.4.2 + v4.4W, on both Windows8.1 and MacOSX 10.9.4. It's Unity v4.6b17.

I'm guessing it's a build issue with my .jar file as Unity apparently can't find the class I'm referencing by string in the call. I have experience writing Unity plug-ins for iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's to do with this line:

```
using (AndroidJavaClass androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("EstimoteBeaconActivity"))
```

The string you type in, should be the string including the namespace it belongs to. So in an eclipse project you might find the class belongs in a certain package such as:

com.companyname.projectname.classname.

You would need to use that same directory in your declaration of your android java class.

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.companyname.projectname.classname");
```

If it's an activity, you also need to make sure it's declared in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The package name is "com.colabproductions.UCC" so at some point I did indeed try AndroidJavaClass androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.colabproductions.UCC.EstimoteBeaconActivity"), however it doesn't help. The activity is indeed declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Have you tried all of that in lowercase? And you have the jar file with the class in your plugins folder Plugins/Android

Answer (score 0):

This no longer throws:

```
    public static bool Initialize(ref string zMsg)
    {
        if (instance_ == null)
        {
            GameObject newGameObject = new GameObject("EstimoteDeviceController");
            newGameObject.AddComponent<EstimoteDevicePlugin>();
            instance_ = newGameObject.GetComponent<EstimoteDevicePlugin>();

        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            try
            {
                instance_.androidActivity_ = new AndroidJavaClass("com.colabproductions.UCC.EstimoteBeaconActivity");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                zMsg = e.StackTrace;
                Debug.LogWarning("[EstimoteDevicePlugin] - Initialize(): exception thrown: " + zMsg);
                return false;
            }
        #endif

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Digging through the patchwork of docs related to this topic it occurred to me to just try to initialise my java.lang.Class with AndroidJavaClass and see if I got back a valid reference to a C# object that was callable. From the above code you can call static methods/members, but the constructor isn't yet called so no instance methods/members are available. This tells me that the activity has not been "automatically constructed" as described in the Android developer docs. Sadly, the constructor is private so I can't call it either.